# KLMS in machine learning

Tags: neural-network, kernel

As Least Mean Square is a very popular choice to be used in combination with neural networks topologies, what would be the most common machine learning algorithms (and easily) to combine with Kernel Least Mean Square?

Comment: is [this](https://www.math.uh.edu/~razencot/MyWeb/docs/workshop/NicolaosMitsakos_KernelRegression.pdf) helpful?

Comment: Thank you. My understanding is that we have LMS - an adaptive filter whose idea is found in ML algorithms, like neural networks. We have ML algorithms (like SVM, PCA) capable of working with kernel functions. And LMS is another example of algorithm  capable of operating with kernels, but it does not involve to be combined with a specific ML algorithm.

Comment: Well options are open! For example, [backpropagation the main algorithm of Neural Networks training is an adaptation of LMS algorithm](https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~nisansa/Classes/01_University_of_Moratuwa/05_CS4622_Machine_Learning_Sem_7_(2013)/Lecture_08_-_Neural_Networks_-_LMS_and_Backpropagation.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, again. But something it's still unclear.  Do we can say that there are ML algorithms inspired by KLMS (and what would be these, if yes) in the same way neural network's backpropagation is inspired by LMS ?

Answer (score 0):

If Kernel Least Mean Square (KLMS) is to be applied, it would be useful to most augment traditional machine learning (e.g., linear regression).

KLMS are not common in machine learning because kernel methods require more both memory space and computational power. Kernel methods definitely increase the training time while probably not significantly increasing the ability to model the data relative to tree-based models and neural networks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.